# Make Android Custom App Bar as Default in every Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appbar

I want to make android custom app bar that contains searchbox, icon, etc.

The solution on google that I found was changing the style to no action bar. And create a toolbar layout that need to be included in every activity I made.

I just wondering, can I make custom App bar that default appear in every activity without including them when creating Activity?

Comment: can you add your xml code and your activity code?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using v7.widget.toolbar. At first you need to create custom layout for your toolbar. Then you need to set it as a support action bar in each activity that you want it to appear. Toolbar on every activity can contains different icons.
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: thanks, but I just curious if I can make it apply to all activity as default without included custom toolbar in every activity..
But I think this is the best solution so far